# Amcharts 4 Date Axis tooltip is showing wrong day for each week (Monday instead of Friday)

Tags: amcharts

I am using Amcharts 4 to display a date series line graph. The dates are sequntial on a weekly basis and each date falls on a Friday. If I add the date value to the series tooltip, It does show the correct date, which is the Friday of each week. However, the date axis tooltip shows the Monday date, even though none of the dates in my chart data are Mondays. They are all Fridays. Anyone know why and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For weekly data, you must indicate first day of a week, which default is Monday. So in your case this should fix things:

```
chart.dateFormatter.firstDayOfWeek = 5;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. I appreciate it.